# Synapse - "Failed handle request via 'ThumbnailResource': <XForwardedForRequest at"

Tags: nginx, matrix

My Synapse log is picking up a lot of these errors, not sure how to stop it:

/var/log/matrix-synapse/homeserver.log

```
2020-05-07 12:04:58,581 - synapse.http.server - 110 - ERROR - GET-10514 - Failed handle request via 'ThumbnailResource': <XForwardedForRequest at 0x7f12fc6ce080 method='GET' uri='/_matrix/media/v1/thumbnail/shortestpath.dev/gKSerLYhLEsdOmcHGPrCxEar?width=250&height=250&method=scale' clientproto='HTTP/1.0' site=8008>
2020-05-07 12:05:09,762 - synapse.http.server - 110 - ERROR - GET-10516 - Failed handle request via 'ThumbnailResource': <XForwardedForRequest at 0x7f12b96043c8 method='GET' uri='/_matrix/media/v1/thumbnail/shortestpath.dev/gKSerLYhLEsdOmcHGPrCxEar?width=250&height=250&method=scale' clientproto='HTTP/1.0' site=8008>
2020-05-07 12:05:27,810 - synapse.http.server - 110 - ERROR - GET-10544 - Failed handle request via 'ThumbnailResource': <XForwardedForRequest at 0x7f12ca70c0f0 method='GET' uri='/_matrix/media/v1/thumbnail/shortestpath.dev/gKSerLYhLEsdOmcHGPrCxEar?width=250&height=250&method=scale' clientproto='HTTP/1.0' site=8008>
2020-05-07 12:05:44,605 - synapse.http.server - 110 - ERROR - GET-10545 - Failed handle request via 'ThumbnailResource': <XForwardedForRequest at 0x7f129c48a278 method='GET' uri='/_matrix/media/v1/thumbnail/shortestpath.dev/gKSerLYhLEsdOmcHGPrCxEar?width=250&height=250&method=scale' clientproto='HTTP/1.0' site=8008>
2020-05-07 12:05:49,011 - synapse.http.server - 110 - ERROR - GET-10592 - Failed handle request via 'ThumbnailResource': <XForwardedForRequest at 0x7f12ca611b00 method='GET' uri='/_matrix/media/v1/thumbnail/maunium.net/KxbEPqRBwziUsFeOBadXZkPw?width=250&height=250&method=scale' clientproto='HTTP/1.0' site=8008>
2020-05-07 12:06:04,768 - synapse.http.server - 110 - ERROR - GET-10593 - Failed handle request via 'ThumbnailResource': <XForwardedForRequest at 0x7f13345c6f60 method='GET' uri='/_matrix/media/v1/thumbnail/maunium.net/KxbEPqRBwziUsFeOBadXZkPw?width=250&height=250&method=scale' clientproto='HTTP/1.0' site=8008>
2020-05-07 12:06:15,937 - synapse.http.server - 110 - ERROR - GET-10612 - Failed handle request via 'ThumbnailResource': <XForwardedForRequest at 0x7f12c3887630 method='GET' uri='/_matrix/media/v1/thumbnail/maunium.net/KxbEPqRBwziUsFeOBadXZkPw?width=250&height=250&method=scale' clientproto='HTTP/1.0' site=8008>
2020-05-07 12:06:41,387 - synapse.http.server - 110 - ERROR - GET-10753 - Failed handle request via 'ThumbnailResource': <XForwardedForRequest at 0x7f12c2098e10 method='GET' uri='/_matrix/media/v1/thumbnail/maunium.net/KxbEPqRBwziUsFeOBadXZkPw?width=250&height=250&method=scale' clientproto='HTTP/1.0' site=8008>
2020-05-07 12:06:48,556 - synapse.http.server - 110 - ERROR - GET-10785 - Failed handle request via 'ThumbnailResource': <XForwardedForRequest at 0x7f12e8e9d710 method='GET' uri='/_matrix/media/v1/thumbnail/maunium.net/KxbEPqRBwziUsFeOBadXZkPw?width=250&height=250&method=scale' clientproto='HTTP/1.0' site=8008>
2020-05-07 12:07:22,281 - synapse.http.server - 110 - ERROR - GET-10935 - Failed handle request via 'ThumbnailResource': <XForwardedForRequest at 0x7f12b95ce390 method='GET' uri='/_matrix/media/v1/thumbnail/maunium.net/KxbEPqRBwziUsFeOBadXZkPw?width=250&height=250&method=scale' clientproto='HTTP/1.0' site=8008>
```

I noticed the 110 error also appearing in the nginx log:

/var/log/nginx/error.log

```
2020/05/07 12:05:21 [error] 15001#15001: *5208 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 152.83.36.229, server: perthchat.org, request: "GET /_matrix/client/r0/sync?filter=4&timeout=0&since=s13873199_144976577_102_12629240_447081_740_170170_1157565_46 HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8008/_matrix/client/r0/sync?filter=4&timeout=0&since=s13873199_144976577_102_12629240_447081_740_170170_1157565_46", host: "perthchat.org"
2020/05/07 12:05:57 [error] 15001#15001: *24226 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 180.150.86.248, server: perthchat.org, request: "GET /_matrix/client/r0/rooms/!ipNlwKBRqACYoJdWng%3Aperthchat.org/messages?from=t1110-8254271_138296096_190_11987775_441774_735_165774_1097195_45&limit=100&dir=b&filter=%7B%22lazy_load_members%22%3Atrue%7D HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8008/_matrix/client/r0/rooms/!ipNlwKBRqACYoJdWng%3Aperthchat.org/messages?from=t1110-8254271_138296096_190_11987775_441774_735_165774_1097195_45&limit=100&dir=b&filter=%7B%22lazy_load_members%22%3Atrue%7D", host: "perthchat.org"
2020/05/07 12:05:58 [error] 15001#15001: *23974 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 115.64.239.92, server: perthchat.org, request: "GET /_matrix/client/r0/sync?filter=2&timeout=0&since=s13873199_144976577_102_12629240_447081_740_170170_1157565_46 HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8008/_matrix/client/r0/sync?filter=2&timeout=0&since=s13873199_144976577_102_12629240_447081_740_170170_1157565_46", host: "perthchat.org"
2020/05/07 12:05:58 [error] 15001#15001: *24226 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 180.150.86.248, server: perthchat.org, request: "PUT /_matrix/client/r0/rooms/!eKcvxHzuatrhOvJGau%3Aperthchat.org/send/m.room.encrypted/m1588823818734.700 HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8008/_matrix/client/r0/rooms/!eKcvxHzuatrhOvJGau%3Aperthchat.org/send/m.room.encrypted/m1588823818734.700", host: "perthchat.org"
2020/05/07 12:06:45 [error] 15001#15001: *26692 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/config.perthchat.org.json" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 115.64.239.92, server: perthchat.org, request: "GET /config.perthchat.org.json?cachebuster=1588824405343 HTTP/2.0", host: "perthchat.org"
2020/05/07 12:06:49 [error] 15001#15001: *26488 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 180.150.125.11, server: perthchat.org, request: "GET /_matrix/client/r0/sync?timeout=0&filter=2&since=s13873013_144976312_90_12629231_447077_740_170143_1157562_46&set_presence=offline HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8008/_matrix/client/r0/sync?timeout=0&filter=2&since=s13873013_144976312_90_12629231_447077_740_170143_1157562_46&set_presence=offline", host: "perthchat.org"
2020/05/07 12:07:00 [error] 15001#15001: *24226 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 180.150.86.248, server: perthchat.org, request: "GET /_matrix/client/r0/rooms/!XprjixvvQwRFzjVQkl%3Aperthchat.org/messages?from=t39-138928_138296096_190_11987775_441774_735_165774_1097195_45&limit=100&dir=b&filter=%7B%22lazy_load_members%22%3Atrue%7D HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8008/_matrix/client/r0/rooms/!XprjixvvQwRFzjVQkl%3Aperthchat.org/messages?from=t39-138928_138296096_190_11987775_441774_735_165774_1097195_45&limit=100&dir=b&filter=%7B%22lazy_load_members%22%3Atrue%7D", host: "perthchat.org"
2020/05/07 12:07:14 [error] 15001#15001: *24226 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 180.150.86.248, server: perthchat.org, request: "GET /_matrix/client/r0/sync?filter=8&timeout=30000&since=s13873293_144977754_119_12629401_447085_740_170304_1157654_46 HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8008/_matrix/client/r0/sync?filter=8&timeout=30000&since=s13873293_144977754_119_12629401_447085_740_170304_1157654_46", host: "perthchat.org"
2020/05/07 12:07:20 [error] 15001#15001: *5208 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 152.83.36.229, server: perthchat.org, request: "GET /_matrix/client/r0/sync?filter=4&timeout=30000&since=s13873213_144977691_105_12629256_447085_740_170213_1157598_46 HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8008/_matrix/client/r0/sync?filter=4&timeout=30000&since=s13873213_144977691_105_12629256_447085_740_170213_1157598_46", host: "perthchat.org"
2020/05/07 12:07:20 [error] 15001#15001: *23974 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 115.64.239.92, server: perthchat.org, request: "GET /_matrix/client/r0/sync?filter=2&timeout=30000&since=s13873213_144977691_105_12629256_447085_740_170213_1157598_46 HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8008/_matrix/client/r0/sync?filter=2&timeout=30000&since=s13873213_144977691_105_12629256_447085_740_170213_1157598_46", host: "perthchat.org"
```